# Using the Rest API, get all Woocommerce orders for the current day

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I'm using the Woocommerce Rest API to grab orders using the following:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?consumer_key=ck_xxx&consumer_secret=cs_xxx
```

How can I grab the **completed** orders for the **current day**?

Answer (score 1):

All the given answers previously are incorrect; as they query for completed orders that are **published originally** on the given day with the query parameters **after** and **before**. The actual completion date however can be completely different from that day still.

But the original question was how to retrieve the orders that were **completed** on a given day.

For that the following WooCommerce REST API query does the job correctly:

```
[<domain>]/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?modified_after=2023-05-01T00:00:00&modified_before=2023-05-02T00:00:00&status=completed
```

As the completion of an order is normally the last modification to an order querying by **modified_after** and **modified_before** allows for retrieving the orders that were actually completed on the specified day (as opposed to originally published/created/entered on that day).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-orders), you can add GET parameters like "before", "after", and "status" to the retrieve order GET endpoint.
I'd combine those and see what response you get.
I can't test at the moment, but I assume for the completed orders of 2021-12-01, your URL would look like this:

`https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?consumer_key=ck_xxx&consumer_secret=cs_xxx&status=completed&after=2021-11-30&before=2021-12-02`

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue today, and the dates need to be in the following `ISO8601` compliant format:

```
after=2022-12-30T00:00:00

before=2022-12-31T00:00:00
```

So this is how the link should look like:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?consumer_key=ck_xxx&consumer_secret=cs_xxx&status=completed&after=2021-11-30T00:00:00 &before=2021-12-02T00:00:00
```